# Access an object from componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, react-native

I called the following library in `componentDidMount()` and it returns an object successfully.

```
  componentDidMount() {
      var objData =call.MyLibStart('12121', this);
}
```

Now I need to use `objData` in `render()` section. I also need to access some attribute of the `objData` such as, `objData.`

```
 render() {
//I need the object.postate here
}
```

How can I access an object there? Is using a the state a good idea here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the object just like @3Dos's answer. If you want to modify the value of `objData`, then use it as a state. If you only want to render that object or get the value to check for something then a class property is enough.

Make sure you're getting the object the right way:

```
componentWillMount () {
  this.objData = Object.assign({}, call.MyLibStart('12121', this))
  console.log('objData: ', this.objData) // inspect the object in debugger to check it's keys
}
```

The reason with `componentDidMount` is it only run after the `render` function. Your app's flow goes like this:

1. in `constructor()`: `this.objData = null`
2. in `render()`: `this.objData = null`
3. in `componentDidMount()`: `this.objData = some object`

At this time render function will not be updated because it will only update if you have made some changes to your state. Since `this.objData` is not a state so it will always be null in `render`. So by changing `componentDidMount` to `componentWillMount` your `objData` won't be null when `render` got called.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. in fact, I need this:  objData.feature1;

Comment: Just I need to use it, I don't need to modify it, so I do not use state.

Comment: Also, according the above answer, the 'objData' is undefined in render() function.

Comment: It gave me again undefined.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is probably to set an instance variable in a constructor so you can access it in your other class methods like for exemple :

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.objData = call.MyLibStart('12121', this)
  }

  render () {
    // Do whatever you like with this.objData
    return null
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forget to say that, I need to access some attributes of 'objData'. For example I need objData.activeSection. How ever it is undefined there. Can you help me?

Comment: Are sure `objData.activeSection` is defined ? what does `console.log(this.objData)` outputs in `componentDidMount` and in `render` ?

Comment: also make sure to access `this.objData.activeSection` instead of `objData.activeSection`

Comment: It is again undefined! :(

Comment: And what about `console.log` ? Are you sure `call.MyLibStart()` returns an object with the `activeSection` property ?

Comment: Yes, I have checked it and it returns correctly. I think the description of 
@Huy Vo is correct. So, the reason that I have a undefined in render()  is, componentDidMount () executed after the render() as he said.

Comment: You're right, so check my post. I edited it. This should work for you

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need access to mounted components, you could set it as initial state in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    objData: call.MyLibStart('12121', this)
  }
}
render() {
  // use this.state.objData here
}
```

Comment: It shows it undefine again. Should I bind it in constructor also?

Comment: Thanks for your answer in advance.